# Facebook sharing from android app, post preview

Tags: android, facebook

Here is my current running Facebook Api:

```
        Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", postParams,
                HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
```

Preview with this "me/photos" Api on Facebook after sharing from app:
[image]

I want to see my post on Facebook like below:

[image]

Please let me know, where i'm wrong, any idea will be appreciated,Thanks

Comment: I'm using custom dialog for sharing and taken permission from Facebook "publish_actions"

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph

Comment: Thanks exact link for custom is  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom